# How to loop through array of objects and add new object key based on condition in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, conditional-statements, mapping, data-augmentation

I have the following array of objects:

```
[{"id":0,"name":"Katy","age":22},
{"id":2,"name":"Lucy","age":12},
{"id":1,"name":"Jenna","age":45},
{"id":3,"name":"Ellie","age":34}]
```

I need to add another key into the objects (`PaymentCategory`) where whichever object has the lowest ID is added the key with value "Cash", the one with highest ID "Card", and everything in between "Cheque"; the array also must then be sorted by ID.

Hence required output would be:

```
[{"PaymentCategory":"Cash","id":0,"name":"Katy","age":22},
{"Payment Category":"Cheque","id":1,"name":"Jenna","age":45},
{"Payment Category":"Cheque","id":2,"name":"Lucy","age":12},
{"Payment Category":"Card","id":3,"name":"Ellie","age":34}]
```

How can we achieve this result in the most efficient way, i.e. fewest number of iterations, highest performance?

Here's what I tried:

```
const min = array.reduce((prev,curr)=> prev.id<curr.id?prev:curr)
  const max = array.reduce((prev,curr)=> prev.id>curr.id?prev:curr)
  min.PaymentCategory = "Cash"
  max.PaymentCategory = "Credit"
  const result =[min, max]
```

The problem with this is:

1. I'm looping through it twice, one for `max`, one for `min`.
2. How do I get the "middle" values?

Comment: Sorry @Peter Seliger for the late reply and answer acception, I had lost my account access in between, hence couldn't see/accept answers. Thanks Peter Seliger and Ali for taking time for answering this question, I was able to verify the output through code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following provided approach is straightforward and first does [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the items of a shallow array copy ([`[...sampleData]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#copy_an_array)) in an ascending order ( `.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)` ) of  `id` values.

The final task does [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each (sorted) item in a way which creates a shallow copy ([`{ ...item }`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#syntax)) and in addition creates a `'Payment Category'` entry where the first item ( `idx === 0` ) gets assigned the `'Cash'` value, the last item ( `(idx === arr.length - 1)` ) gets assigned the `'Card'` value, and all other get assigned the `'Cheque'` value.

The entire approach does not mutate the originally provided data ...

```js
const sampleData = [
  { id: 0, name: "Katy", age: 22 },
  { id: 2, name: "Lucy", age: 12 },
  { id: 1, name: "Jenna", age: 45 },
  { id: 3, name: "Ellie", age: 34 },
];

console.log(
  'mapped `sampleData` items ...',

  [...sampleData]
    .sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)
    .map((item, idx, arr) => ({
      ...item,
      'Payment Category': ((idx === 0)
        && 'Cash') || ((idx === arr.length - 1)
        && 'Card') || 'Cheque',
    }))
);
console.log('unmutated `sampleData` ...', sampleData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

The above approach in an even more readable way ...

```js
const copyItemAndAugmentPaymentCategory = (item, idx, arr) => ({
  ...item,
  'Payment Category': ((idx === 0)
    && 'Cash') || ((idx === arr.length - 1)
    && 'Card') || 'Cheque',
});
const compareItemIdPrecedenceAscending = (a, b) => a.id - b.id;

console.log(
  [
    { id: 0, name: "Katy", age: 22 },
    { id: 2, name: "Lucy", age: 12 },
    { id: 1, name: "Jenna", age: 45 },
    { id: 3, name: "Ellie", age: 34 },
  ]
  .sort(compareItemIdPrecedenceAscending)
  .map(copyItemAndAugmentPaymentCategory)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

```js
const array =[{"id":0,"name":"Katy","age":22},
{"id":2,"name":"Lucy","age":12},
{"id":1,"name":"Jenna","age":45},
{"id":3,"name":"Ellie","age":34}]

const arrayLength= array.length
  
const newA=array.map( (element,index) =>  { if (index===0) return {"PaymentCategory":"Cash", ...element}
else if ( index===arrayLength-1 )return {"PaymentCategory":"Card", ...element}
else return {"PaymentCategory":"Cheque", ...element}})
```

check map method in arrays to learn more : https://learnjsx.com/category/2/posts/es6-mapFunction

Comment: What if the id is not equivalent to the length of the array?